# BIOS won't save settings, Lenovo laptop

Tags: boot, laptop, bios

Some time ago, I've set a password for BIOS administrator and user. Recently, I've wanted to remove them, but when I entered BIOS and cleared the password (then save, exit and reboot), I was prompted to enter it again.

BIOS won't save any setting (not even boot order), apart from time and date.

I've checked my CMOS CR2032 battery and it's perfectly good. Something doesn't let BIOS save settings.

Any ideas will be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

P.S.: Laptop is a Lenovo B50-80.

Comment: If you can, Please try to update the BIOS to latest version.